# Turn on/off local wifi device with bash script

Tags: raspberry-pi, alexa-skills-kit, google-home, google-smart-home

I have a raspberry pi in my local wifi network. Also I bought smart socket which can be integrated with  Alexa or Google Home Assistant. What is a best option to turn the socket on/off from my raspberry?
I thought about installing alexa or google home assistant on the raspberry and somehow use one of these to control my socket. However I don't want to do that by voice but simply a bash script.

Comment: What socket are you using? The manufacturer might have their own API that you can use.

Comment: It's called ITINFTEK SP1.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any API for that device as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to control the local wifi device with a bash script. You can use [ifconfig](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ifconfig) to bring an interface up/down and configure it accordingly. But, it also depends on the integration of the smart socket with Alexa/Assistant, whether the manufacturer provides their own API endpoints for you to use or whether the user interacts through Assistant/Alexa. If you are using Google Assistant, you can leverage automations on Google Home App to control the device automatically.